# swift2 AVAudioRecorder

Tags: ios, swift2

I am trying the following code using swift 2, which should be fine in swift 1.

```
class NewSoundViewController: UIViewController {
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let audioURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents([
        NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0],
        "MyAudio.m4a"
    ])
    do {
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    } catch {
        print("Session errors.")
    }

    do {
        let recordSettings: [String: AnyObject] = [
            AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
            AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
        ]
        self.audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioURL!, settings: recordSettings)
        self.audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true
        self.audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()

    } catch let error as NSError{
        print(error.description)
    } catch {
        print("Other errors")            
    }
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

I got compiling error

**Type 'AudioFormatID' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'`**

at the line `AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,`.

If I comment out the line, I passed build, but got a runtime error

**Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1718449215 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1718449215.)"**

I also tried `AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(unsignedInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),`, and got runtime error. Xcode seemed go to debug mode It red highlighted `self.audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioURL!, settings: recordSettings)` and said

**Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0)**

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 3):

> I also tried `AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(unsignedInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)`

Well, that is the correct thing to say. Basically you are asking *two* questions here; the compiler error you've already solved. Now you're having a runtime error, but that's completely different matter.

As for the runtime error, it's probably just a figment of trying to test on the Simulator. I ran your code on the device (after fixing the line in question so that it would compile) and it's fine.

**EDIT** In a comment, you revealed that you tested this on a device running iOS 8.3. That's the problem! You need to test on a device, and it needs to be a device running iOS 9. Then you'll find that your code runs without crashing.

Comment: Hmmm...I printed out `audioURL` and it showed `MyAudio.m4a` so I assume it is not nil.

Comment: I tested your code and it runs fine on the device. You're probably just getting a problem on the Simulator because you can't record there.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for either my iPhone or the simulator. Thanks for your testing anyway!.

Comment: The only change I made was to replace that one expression `AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC` with `AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(unsignedInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)`. The rest is _exactly_ as you have it. It launches without crashing. Do you need me to send you a copy of my test project? — Also, did you remember to update your device to iOS 9?

Comment: It is very nice if you can send me your test project. I appreciate it. I didn't update my device to iOS9, but I change the build of my project to iOS8.3.

Comment: But that's your problem right there. You can't build for iOS 8 using Xcode 7 beta. Well, obviously you can, but the results are not reliable. During this early beta period, you must build and run for iOS 9 only. I'm surprised that Xcode didn't tell you that your device was ineligible.

Comment: @matt - not sure if it's a recent change, but i can record fine on the simulator - the path ends up something like: /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E1072655-3B33-4FD5-B37F-A7485D6876CB/data/Containers/Data/Application/49EF85BC-218C-4BCD-BAF0-5724789CDE1F/Documents [on the Mac]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with the settings. AVFormatIDKey was not accepted with the error mentioned in the original post.

The recordSettings needs to be explicitly casted in Swift 2.

These are my settings for recording that works. If I just skipped the AVFormatIDKey, the microphone only worked for a fraction of a second.

```
let recordSettings = [AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(float: Float(44100.0)),
        AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(kAudioFormatAppleLossless)),
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber(int: 1),
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(AVAudioQuality.Medium.rawValue)),
        AVEncoderBitRateKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(320000))]
```

You don't need to upgrade the device to iOS 9. I built and ran this for iOS 8.4

Comment: this was *extremely* helpful, thank you. I've been chasing this for days.

Answer (score 0):

I  had a similar issue and it turns out that when I updated from swift 1.2 to 2.0  the signature of "settings" changed to a non optional [String : AnyObject]

```
//Swift 1.2
AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioURL!, settings: nil)
```

if I pass an empty dictionary it doesn't crash for me anymore and works as before.

```
//Swift 2.0    
AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioURL!, settings: [:])
```